# issue with CORS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

I have nodejs backend with below CORS config:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept")
        next()
    })
```

on frontend, sending request like this

```
Axios({
    method: "GET",
    url: `${REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL}/${endpoint}`,
    data: body,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
    },
  });
```

but on my site, I show error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.example.com/api/category' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

What wrong with my config? Yesterday, it works fine, I dont know why it suddently happend today.

Comment: The CORS acceptance headers need to be served from `api.example.com`

Comment: You mean this line from backend? `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`, I changed it to domain name before but doesn't work.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: So you are posting to your own server and you started to get CORS error?

Comment: @epascarello yes, I can config my server. In past I just use `app.use(cors())` for backend and no header for frontend, it worked, but from today, this happends.

Comment: The error message exactly tells you what's missing. The Access-Control-Allow-Headers header contained in the response of the preflight request does not contain the Authorization header you try to send ... And there is no point in sending the cors headers from the client to the server, they have to be correctly sent from the server to the client

Comment: @derpirscher I change my backend to `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,**Authorization**');` but still no luck

Comment: And you still got the *same* error message? Can you inspect the preflight request and response in the developer tools of your browser? Is the Authorization correctly contained in the ACAH header of that response?

Comment: "Request header field **authorization** is not allowed by **Access-Control-Allow-Headers** in preflight response" Once that mistake is fixed, I expect you will get a different error.

Comment: I tried many methods but still got CORS error. I also change ngnix as well. It worked before, then CORS showing.

Answer (score -1):

CORS came into the picture mainly when REST servers started being popular. It is a browser security feature not server's. Normally browsers don't want to render any content which is coming from an unrecognized source. So whenever a website (frontend) requests any data from any server side (backend), the server needs to basically tell the browser that "This is a safe content, make it accessable" by putting the necessary CORS headers in the response headers.

To check this, if you want to receive any data from a source which is giving CORS error, then [Check this article](https://alfilatov.com/posts/run-chrome-without-cors/) to disable chrome security. Disable the security and run again. You will no longer see those errors.

NOTE: This is not recommended at all.

This is what I normally use:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization");
```

When asterisk (*) is used, the content can be accessed by any origin. You can also specify origins like this:

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://stackoverflow.com');
```

Or you can use a npm module [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to make life easy.

Read this article to know more about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).